# JQuery calls Knockout ViewModel

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, single-page-application

i'm pretty much a beginner in Knockout 
After some time of working i tracked a little problem (I'm trying to build a mobile SPA):

if i bind JQuery and Knockout in my project my ViewModel gets called twice:

```
  @{
        Layout=null;
    }

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
             // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
             // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page, or when clicking "back"
             // after a form post), hence disabling it.
             $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
         });
    </script>

    @*jquery löst ViewMOdel aus*@

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/upshot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/Upshot_Timeworx.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Login Seite -->
    <form data-bind="visible: userNotLoggedIn">  

        <label>Mandant</label><br /> <input data-bind="value: mandant" type="text" name="Mandant" />
        <br />
        <label>Benutzername</label><br /> <input data-bind="value: user" type="text" name="Benutzername"/>
        <br />
        <label>Passwort</label><br /> <input data-bind="value: password" type="password" name="Passwort"/>
        <br />

        <input type="button" value="Anmelden" name="login" data-bind="click: login" align="middle" />

    </form>
    <!-- ----------------------------------  -->


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
  function AppViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            var time = new Date();

            //Der User ist noch nicht angemeldet
            self.userNotLoggedIn = ko.observable(true);

            //Die Startseite wird versteckt
            self.showStart = ko.observable(false);

            //Die Detailseite wird versteckt 
            self.showDetails = ko.observable(false);



            //----------------------------------------------//
            //LogInSeite
            self.mandant = ko.observable("");
            self.user = ko.observable("");
            self.password = ko.observable("");

            //Überprüfen ob Passwort übereinstimmt
            self.login = function () {
                var pass = self.password();
                //alert(pass); Überprüfen ob das richtige passwort gespeichert wurde

                //!!!!!! ES MÜSSEN NOCH DIE ZUGANGSDATEN AUS DER DATENBANK EINGESETZT WERDEN!!!!!"
                if ((self.password() == "gregrech") && (self.user() == "Gregor")) {
                    //Code um die LogInSeite zu schließen 
                    //und die Startseite zu zeigen
                    //self.userNotLoggedIn(false);
                    self.showStart(true);
                    self.userNotLoggedIn(false);    //Die Log In Seite wird im Hintergrund versteckt

                }
                else {
                    alert("Username oder Passwort nicht korrekt");
                }

            }


            //Hier Endet der Knockout-Code für die LogIn-Seite
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


            //StartSeite
            self.details = function () {
                self.showStart(false);
                self.showDetails(true);
                //Funktioniert noch nicht
                //self.projectName = self.projectDetails.projectName();

            }
            //--------------------------------------------//

        ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel);
    });
</script>
```

if i try to run this code the messagebox form the alert comes twice, but only JQuery mobile is bound in!

Does anyone know what my problem is?
if i try to run this the messagebox form the alert comes twice, but only JQuery mobile is bound in!

Does anyone know what my problem is?

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of your code? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code you've provided, but the problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: It works fine if i don't use jqery mobile! I already tried JS Fiddle, but it worked fine there!

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC4 if this helps...

It seems like JQuery is validates the whole viewmodel of my knockout script

Comment: When you say that the alert appears "twice"....do you mean that you're getting a system alert and a jQuery modal alert? Are the popping up one after the other or at the same time? Or do you mean something else entirely? You might try specifically using a jQuery modal call instead of the Javascript `alert()` call that you're using.

Comment: These are two system alerts.
The first one appears and if i press the OK-Button the other one pops up..
I have no idea what the could be the reason for this...
Hm.. I think you're not quiet understanding my problem.
The problem is that all the other code of my ViewModel also is done multiple times. 
For Example: I have a table with a foreach binding and an observable array with three elements. 
If i run the code the table has 9 elements (each element three times).
If Jquery is not bound in it works propperly...

Comment: Post all of your code - we'll see if we can find what's wrong.

Comment: I have posted the code now! 
Maybe you can help me afther this

Comment: anyone aleready knows my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $(document).ready with jQuery mobile pages [isn't reliable](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/04/document-ready-for-jquery-mobile/). This may be causing your problem.

In your current code, you're implicitly using .ready via the call:

```
$(function() { ...
```

Instead, use the [pageinit event](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/events.html):

```
$('#aboutPage').live( 'pageinit', function(event) {
   // Create and bind your Knockout view model here.
});
```